# Post video on a fan page on facebook using php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am having videos uploaded by users on my live site. I have created an admin panel where the admin reviews all the videos and if he wish that video to be posted on facebook then he has a button as `Post to Wall` infront of each video.

I have seen [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/) tutorial but still unable to post videos on a fan page. I also found one more [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) but according to this we can upload video only if it is on our local machine.

My problem is I want to upload video which is on my server not on my local machine. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Code for upload on fb:

```
$message = array('source' => 'http://bizmoapps.com/icstories/uploads/video/52e113c822271vid-20130707-wa0000.mp4');
$url = '/' . $_POST['pageid'] . '/photos';
$result = $fb->api($url, 'POST', $message);
 if ($result) {
       echo 'Data posted successfully';
  }
```

Comment: Ummm ... some code? what have you tried so far? that should be pretty easy

Comment: From the docs: _“Videos must be encoded as multipart/form-data”_ – whereas you are trying to just give the URL as `source` parameter value. Go do some research on how to make a multipart/form-data POST request with PHP.